# Creating bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sar

How to create a bash script that runs periodically through a cronjob to gather readings of a running processes on the current machine (1 sample per process on each run ) from the system the readings are:
1 CPU load percentage.
2 Memory Usage.
3 Open files count.
4 Open ports count.

Comment: you can use `sar` utility for this.

Comment: @Siddharthsharma, I think **`sar`** reports for the whole system, not for individual processes -- Perhaps I misunderstood the question because of "a running process**es**".

Answer (score 0):

I gues you could iterate through `/proc` filesystem analysing files `uid` and `stat*`. Then the uid needs to be mapped to `/etc/passwd` to get real user names. In my opinion a perl script would be more convenient for this need.